# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have used Devise gem in my rails app. When I click on logout it takes me to an error page that is:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Extracted source (around line #181):
        def handle_unverified_request
          raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
        end
      end
    end
```

On refreshing the same page, it works correctly and user gets logged out.
The error occurred after i run `rake db:reset`, before it was running fine

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you logging out your users? Are you using `remote: true` or some custom form?

Comment: <%= link_to :Logout, destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %> this is the line to log out

Comment: Do you have `jquery_ujs` javascript included in your page?

Comment: yes it is included

Comment: I think its something to do with `require jquery_ujs` as i comment this line it works fine.

Comment: See if the `authenticity_token` is being sent in the DevTools' "Network" tab.